# What is meaning behind "Carbon" platform which is related to WSO2ESB

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server, wso2-esb

I am new to WSO2ESB currently i have read that WSO2ESB is a carbon platform . I am totally confused what is the meaning of "Carbon" platform  which is related to WSO2ESB.

Comment: It's not Crabon, it's Carbon. I will edit your post

Answer (score 0):

WSO2 Carbon is award-winning platfom on which all of the WSO2 products built.

WSO2 ESB also built on top of Carbon platform. You can consider Carbon platform as a framework, consisting of a collection of OSGi bundles, WSO2 Carbon hosts components for integration, security, clustering, governance, statistics, and other features in the middleware space.

BTW, in 2009, it received [Best of Open Source Software (Bossie) Award](http://wso2.com/about/news/wso2-wins-infoworld-best-of-open-source-award-for-wso2-carbon/).